# pyparsing dropping space and merging tokens

Tags: python, space, pyparsing

I am trying to parse some verilog code and I am hoping to just parse sections of it. I don't know pyparsing well enough to write a full parser. I am working on a port section. Here it can have optional tags like "input" and "output". So the following are valid ports:

```
random_signal
input random_signal
```

The problem I have is someone picked a port name:

```
input1
```

When I parse this line, pyparser separates the line into "input" and "1".

Here is what I have:

```
from pyparsing import alphas, nums
from pyparsing import Literal, Group, Optional, Word

port_name = Word( alphas + nums + "_") | "\\do "
in_type = Literal("input") | Literal("output") | Literal("RFnet") | Literal("inout")
var_real = Literal("var") + Literal("real")
bus_index = Word( nums )
in_bus = Literal("[") + bus_index + Optional(":") + Optional(bus_index) + Literal("]")
in_pin = Group(Optional(in_type) + Optional(var_real) + Optional(Literal("wire")) +
               Optional(in_bus) +
               port_name.setResultsName('port_name', listAllMatches=True))

# Test some ports
in_list = ['random_signal', 'input random_signal', 'input1', 'input input1']
for in_str in in_list:
    print in_str, in_pin.parseString(in_str)
```

Here is the output:

```
random_signal [['random_signal']]
input random_signal [['input', 'random_signal']]
input1 [['input', '1']]
input input1 [['input', 'input1']]
```

I would like input1 to return: [['input1']]

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Every place where you enclose a word in `Literal`, try using `Keyword` instead. This will prevent accidentally matching the leading part of a longer identifier, since `Keyword` enforces leading and trailing word breaks.

Comment: Also, there is Verilog parser included in the examples in the pyparsing GitHub repo.

Comment: @PaulMcG that you so much! The Keyword worked. I will also look at the included verilog parser.